# Why is reading response body after calling http.Get(..) causing resource leaks even though I am closing the response body?

Tags: go

```
func getRespBody(link string) (string, error) {

    res, err := http.Get(link)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    resBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return string(resBody), nil
}
```

and I have a test -

```
func TestRespBody(t *testing.T) {
    defer goleak.VerifyNone(t)
    getRespBody("https://google.com")
}
```

Why does this cause resource leaks?

I was hoping that `defer res.Body.Close()` would take care of closing the resp body and there wouldn't be resource leak(s). What should be done in here to prevent resource leaks?

Comment: What is leaked? Are you sure what is reported as leak is not an HTTP connection and/or resources associated with it that is cached in the http client?

Comment: @BurakSerdar The test fails with `found unexpected goroutines: [Goroutine 13 in state IO wait, with internal/poll.runtime_pollWait on top of the stack..` error.

Comment: That looks like an http connection. The http client will cache open connections, and those are reported as leaks. They are not leaks.

Comment: @BurakSerdar is there any way to ignore these in tests? Or rather how do I go about testing for memleaks in my code when something like this is involved?

Comment: You can't test memory leaks for code that leaves state alive after it returns, like http connections. If you suspect leak, you profile it and look at memory usage. You can tweak the http client to not cache connections, but that would invalidate the test because what you're testing would be an artificial use case that never happens in reality. I suggest you use that leak detection library sparingly. Not everything can be tested. You may trick yourself to test scenarios that will never happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying TCP connections used within the HTTP calls, are not closed by default when you close the response body, because it is advantageous to reuse them. This is normal, but that's also the cause of your false positive leak.

You can modify the default http client behavior if you set DisableKeepAlives true.

If you refactor your function to receive an HTTP client as an argument, you can craft an http client which explicitly closes the connection rather than saving it in the connection pool, just in the scope of that test.

```golang
func getResBody(c http.Client, url string) (string, error) {
    res, err := c.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    resBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return string(resBody), nil
}


func Test_getResBody(t *testing.T) {
    defer goleak.VerifyNone(t)

    client := http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            DisableKeepAlives: true,
        },
    }

    getResBody(client, "https://google.com")
}
```